# document.location.href for relative path

Tags: javascript

I want to relocate on button click to a **relative url**:

```
<button onclick="document.location.href='/Recruiters.aspx'"></button>
```

but this is not working...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try with `window.location.href`.

Comment: Is the button inside a form?

Comment: @Brugnar...nope does not work

Comment: @DavidVanStaden `window.location.href` wouldn't fix it, but it's preferred over `document.location.href`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default `type` of a button is `"submit"` so when inside a form, clicking the button submits it. Though it should first redirect but it's worth a shot:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/Recruiters.aspx'"></button>
```

Comment: yup you're right. Defaulting it to type='Button' did the trick. thank you

Comment: Alternatively, you could have your onclick script return false which would cancel the submit while maintaining the type of the button (if you needed it to still be a submit for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick needs to be a handler. You could do it like this:

```
<script>
    function redirect()
    {
        window.location.href='/Recruiters.aspx';
    }
</script>

<button onclick="redirect()"></button>
```

If you don't want to use a handler you can still do it inline like this:

```
<button onclick="javascript: window.location.href='/Recruiters.aspx';"></button>
```